# WPF Datagrid which displays Access Database not editable

Tags: wpf, database, xaml, ms-access, datagrid

I would like to be able to edit data in a datagrid and the changes I make to be saved back to the database from where I take them.

My grid in the xaml is like this:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                        <DataGrid Name="dg_Misc" Margin="2" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black" Foreground="Black"/>
</DockPanel>
```

and I populate it like this:

```
public void CaricaGrid()
    {
        OleDbConnection connessione = new OleDbConnection();

        connessione.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
        connessione.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select* from [Miscellanea]";
        cmd.Connection = connessione;
        OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dg_Misc.ItemsSource = rd;
        dg_Misc.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

The data from the database is displayed well into the datagrid and I find this method really simple and quick however I can't modify the grid's cells. 
I'm also sure the datagrid is enabled since I can select rows and cells.

Comment: This link might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084831/two-way-wpf-datagrid-binding-to-database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through the net I found a solution which work form me, so I'm gonna leave it there in case anyone needs it.

```
public void CaricaGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            connessione = new OleDbConnection();

            connessione.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\DatabaseInventario.accdb";

            if (connessione.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connessione.Open();
            }

            AttaccaGrid();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show(messErrDb); }
    }

private void AttaccaGrid()
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connessione;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM Miscellanea";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dg_Misc.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
        dg_Misc.Items.Refresh();
    }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CaricaGrid();
    }
```

Using this methods I have managed to Load an Access Database to a DataGrid in WPF, displying the Database and being able to change the contents of the cells.

In my program I then managed to add items, delete items, clear all items and save the changes made in the datagrid to the database, if you need some of these codes just comment here/send me a message/scream really loudly.

EDIT - Oh yes you gotta save your Database in the bin\Debug folder of your program.